# Can I set a user which can read one database and read/write another database in clickhouse

Tags: readonly, clickhouse, access-rights

Clickhouse offical document implies one user can only have one profile, and database is configured in `user` section, `readonly` is configured in profile section, so, `readonly` will effect on all user's database.
So, how can I set a user `x` which only can read database `dbA`, but can read and write database `dbB`?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [SQL-driven access control management](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/access-rights/#access-control):

1. Prepare test environment:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db_01;
CREATE DATABASE db_02;
CREATE TABLE db_01.table_01 (id Int32) Engine = Memory();
CREATE TABLE db_02.table_02 (id Int32) Engine = Memory();
INSERT INTO db_01.table_01 VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO db_02.table_02 VALUES (10), (20);
```

2. Create user and assign the required privileges:

```sql
CREATE USER user_01 HOST ANY PROFILE 'default';

/* Set readonly access to DB 'db_01'. */
GRANT SELECT ON db_01.* TO user_01;

/* Set read-write access to DB 'db_02'. */
GRANT SELECT ON db_02.* TO user_01;
GRANT INSERT ON db_02.* TO user_01;
```

3. Test (need to login as *user_01*):

```sql
SELECT currentUser(); /* Make sure that user is right. */
/*
┌─currentUser()─┐
│ user_01       │
└───────────────┘
*/

SHOW GRANTS; /* Double check the assigned privileges. */
/*
┌─GRANTS─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ GRANT SELECT ON db_01.* TO user_01         │
│ GRANT INSERT, SELECT ON db_02.* TO user_01 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/

SELECT * FROM db_01.table_01; /* OK */
INSERT INTO db_01.table_01 VALUES (3); /* DB::Exception: user_01: Not enough privileges. */

SELECT * FROM db_02.table_02; /* OK */
INSERT INTO db_02.table_02 VALUES (30); /* OK */
```

The code above is just for the demo, you need to consider introduce roles/quotas/.., inherit another user-profile (more restrictive, not 'default') etc.

Comment: This new functionality seems to be released with new version(20.x), but we are using 18.16 in production. Is there other way to do this? If no, I will consider upgrade version.

Comment: Unfortunately no other way. Maybe make sense to create two separate users - one as writable, second - readonly? (fyi: there is section [allow_databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265589/303298) that can be useful too)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need query several databases in one session, so I have to use the same user. I will consider other solutions or update ck.

Comment: Direct create user is throw error on version 21.12.2.7 . Change it into :   CREATE USER user_01 HOST ANY SETTINGS PROFILE 'default';